# Search in List of dict Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list with some dicts inside. The list looks like this:

```
files = [
{'name': "text.txt", 'size': 10, 'location': "cloud", 'info': "Nothing"},
{'name': "img.jpg", 'size': 200, 'location': "local", 'info': "private"},
{'name': "cars.txt", 'size': 109, 'location': "cloud", 'info': "private"}
]
```

I also have a folder where "text.txt", "img.jpg" and "cars.txt" are located. Somehow I have to get all elements where "location" is "cloud" AND "info" is "Nothing".

The only way to sort the data is by using the "next" function

```
next((item for item in files if item["location"] == "cloud"), None)
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this? And also to sort by "location" and "info"?

Comment: What do you want to do? Sort or search? Your code does not sort the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way will be this

```
list(filter(lambda x: x["location"]=="cloud" and x["info"]=="Nothing",files))
# [{'name': 'text.txt', 'size': 10, 'location': 'cloud', 'info': 'Nothing'}]
```

If you just want the names:

```
list(map(lambda x: x["name"], filter(lambda x: x["location"]=="cloud" and x["info"]=="Nothing",files)))
# ['text.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension, Just iterate throught the dictionaries and get the names.

```
files = [dic['name'] for dic in files if dic['location'] == 'cloud' and dic['info'] == "Nothing"])
print(files)
```

**Output:**

```
['text.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use this as an opportunity to put in a plug for [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/), one of my favorite Python packages for working with structured data.

[`jmespath`](https://jmespath.org), the language, defines a path syntax for locating information embedded in JSON documents (as would be created via json.load(s)).

In your case the solution would be.

```py
In [3]: jmespath.search("[?location == 'cloud' && info == 'Nothing'].name", files)
Out[3]: ['text.txt']
```

Queries can compiled ahead of time.

```py
In [4]: my_search = jmespath.compile("[?location == 'cloud' && info == 'Nothing'].name")

In [5]: my_search.search(files)
Out[5]: ['text.txt']
```

The time invested in learning the path language pays off pretty quick.